# order_with_respect_to for reverse relationship

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()    
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
```

So a Playlist can have multiple songs and a song can be in multiple playlists.

I want to add an "order" field so that a user can reorder songs in a playlist.  I found [order_with_respect_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to), which appears to be a perfect solution.  However, I would need to add that meta option to the `Song` model, e.g.:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'playlists'
```

Obviously, there is no playlist field specified on Song since I've got the relationship specified in the Playlist model.  Is there a way to specify the reverse relationship for `order_with_respect_to` using `related_name`?  Or could I slap a `ForeignKey` reference to playlists in the Song model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order_with_respect_to` is (arguably) useful when you have a `ForeignKey`, but not a `ManyToManyField`. It works by adding an extra field to the model, but in your case the order varies depending on the `Playlist`.

The straightforward way to do this in Django is to put the order on an explicitly created [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) table.

```
class Playlist(models.Model): 
    name = models.TextField()
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song, through='PlaylistSong')

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()

class PlaylistSong(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(Playlist)
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

So to get the `Songs` in a `Playlist` in the right order, you would do something like:

```
Song.objects.filter(playlistsong__playlist_id=1)
            .order_by('playlistsong__order')
```

Comment: Finally got back to this project. This worked perfectly, thanks!